# Modify pandas multiindex value for a particular group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Assume I have a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame with three different levels:

```
arrays = [['2020-03-30', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-30', '2020-04-15', '2020-04-15', '2020-04-15', '2020-05-10', '2020-05-10', '2020-06-10'], ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm2', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1'], ['2022-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2021-01-05', '2021-04-01', '2022-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2021-02-05', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01']]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names = ('Buy_date', 'Firm', 'Sell_date'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(9), index = idx)
df

                               0
Buy_date   Firm  Sell_date      
2020-03-30 Firm1 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2023-02-01  0.0
           Firm2 2021-01-05  0.0
2020-04-15 Firm1 2021-04-01  0.0
           Firm2 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2024-02-01  0.0
2020-05-10 Firm1 2021-02-05  0.0
                 2022-04-01  0.0
2020-06-10 Firm1 2022-04-01  0.0
```

For a given buy date, I want to change the Maximum Sell_date index value of Firm1 and set it to 01.01.2030. So the output should be:

```
Buy_date   Firm  Sell_date      
2020-03-30 Firm1 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2030-01-01  0.0
           Firm2 2021-01-05  0.0
2020-04-15 Firm1 2030-01-01  0.0
           Firm2 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2024-02-01  0.0
2020-05-10 Firm1 2021-02-05  0.0
                 2030-01-01  0.0
2020-06-10 Firm1 2030-01-01  0.0
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I think there's a typo in the expected output in the last row. I think the date should be `'2030-01-01'`

Comment: True, it's edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `set_index` and append a new index level with the required modifications. Also used `groupby.transform` to get the max dates:

```
max_dates = df.reset_index(level='Sell_date').groupby(level=[0,1])['Sell_date'].transform('max')
df = df.set_index(df.index.get_level_values(2)
                  .where((df.index.get_level_values(1)!='Firm1') | 
                         (df.index.get_level_values(2)!=max_dates), '2030-01-01'), 
                  append=True).droplevel(2)
```

A more straightforward way is to use to `reset_index`, modify the DataFrame and set the index with the new columns:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
max_date = df1.groupby(['Buy_date','Firm'])['Sell_date'].transform('max')
df1.loc[df1['Sell_date'].eq(max_date) & df1['Firm'].eq('Firm1'), 'Sell_date'] = '2030-01-01'
df = df1.set_index(['Buy_date','Firm','Sell_date'])
```

Output:

```
                               0
Buy_date   Firm  Sell_date      
2020-03-30 Firm1 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2030-01-01  0.0
           Firm2 2021-01-05  0.0
2020-04-15 Firm1 2030-01-01  0.0
           Firm2 2022-01-01  0.0
                 2024-02-01  0.0
2020-05-10 Firm1 2021-02-05  0.0
                 2030-01-01  0.0
2020-06-10 Firm1 2030-01-01  0.0
```

Comment: These are great suggestions, thank you very much!